# subclass uisearchbar to show text input field instead of scope bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to have a text field input show up instead of a scope bar for uisearchbar?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches.

1. You could subclass UISearchBar and override layoutSubviews, to position your new UITextField.  You'll also probably need to handle setFrame, frame, sizeThatFits, etc.
2. You could create a new composite control, that is, a new control that contains both a USSearchBar and a UITextField.  This is likely the safer and easier approach.